# Почему программа на tkinter работает непостоянно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, окно

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Okno")
root.geometry("600x600")

def calc():
    global root
    global menu
    root.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Okno")
    root.geometry("600x600")    
    bu=Button(text='menu', command=menu).grid()

def menu():
    global root
    global calc
    root.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Okno")
    root.geometry("600x600")
    
    main_menu = Menu()
    menu_menu = Menu()
    
    menu_menu = Menu(font=("Verdana", 13, "bold"), tearoff=0)
    
    menu_menu.add_command(label="Calc", command=calc)
    menu_menu.add_command(label="Menu", command=menu)
    
    main_menu.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=menu_menu)
    
    calc=Button(text="calc", command=calc)
    calc.grid()
    
    root.config(menu=main_menu)
    
menu()
root.mainloop()
```

Попробуйте его запустить: окна будут переключаться несколько раз. А потом программа прекращает работать.

**В чем дело?**

Answer (score 3):

1. В `menu` вы вызываете `root.destroy()`, а его задача - уничтожить окно.
2. Вы затираете функцию `calc`, создавая кнопку.
   После создания кнопки напишите эту строку `print(type(calc))`, и увидите, что теперь это не `function`, а `tkinter.Button`.
3. В функции `calc` вы опять вызываете `root.destroy()`

---

Я бы посоветовал полностью переработать архитектуру приложения дабы избежать использования `global`. Но здесь недостаточно данных, чтобы давать какие-то конкретные советы. Минимальные исправления в вашем коде для работоспособности:

```py
from tkinter import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Okno")
root.geometry("600x600")

def calc():
    global root
    global menu
    root.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Okno")
    root.geometry("600x600")    
    Button(text='menu', command=menu).grid() # <----

def menu():
    global root
    global calc
    root.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Okno")
    root.geometry("600x600")
    
    main_menu = Menu()
    menu_menu = Menu()
    
    menu_menu = Menu(font=("Verdana", 13, "bold"), tearoff=0)
    
    menu_menu.add_command(label="Calc", command=calc)
    menu_menu.add_command(label="Menu", command=menu)
    
    main_menu.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=menu_menu)
    
    Button(text="calc", command=calc).grid() # <----
    
    root.config(menu=main_menu)
    
menu()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: И как же это исправить?

Comment: @CATpython добавил

Comment: Просто используйте класс `class Frame(Tk)`. И не будет у вас глобальных переменных.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. НО где разница между вашим кодом и моим?

Comment: @CATpython я отметил строки, в которых есть изменения `# <----`

Comment: Спасибо! Но по сути, это тоже самое. Почему до этого не работало, когда была задана переменная, а теперь работает?

Comment: @CATpython прочитайте еще раз пункт 2 моего ответа.

Comment: А как понять "затираете"? То есть что происходит и из-за чего?

Comment: @CATpython для простоты можете считать, что вы "удаляете" свою функцию. Хоть это и не совсем точно описывает действительность.